# Program runs in background through cmd even after Process is explicitly closed

Tags: c#, .net, batch-file, asynchronous, process

I have a `Process l_batchProcess` and internally it executes `cmd.exe` which has certain commands related to `CAT.NET cmd`, But when I **explicitly** close the Process instance , I see that it still executes the CAT.NET cmd.exe in the background .

There is another issue; I'm not sure if `l_batchProcess.WaitForExit()` has anything to do keep the process to get back once CAT.NET is completed in background. When I check for `l_batchProcess` it seems the process has exited and tells no process is associated.

Could someone guide me and let me know if more details are required.
`ExecuteBatchFile` is run asynchronously.

```
public string ExecuteBatchFile(BatchFile batchFile)
{
    //var lockObject = new object();
    string returnMessage = string.Empty;
    l_batchProcess.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
        FileName = batchFile.InputFilePath,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    };

    if (File.Exists(batchFile.InputFilePath))
    {
        try
        {
            l_batchProcess.Refresh();
            l_batchProcess.Start();
            processStartedFlag = true;
            l_batchProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
            l_batchProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();
            l_batchProcess.WaitForExit();

            if (l_batchProcess.ExitCode != 0)
                returnMessage = "Errors while executing";
        }
        finally
        {
            CloseProcess();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        returnMessage = "Batch File path incorrect";
    }
    File.Delete(batchFile.InputFilePath);
    return returnMessage;
}

public bool CloseProcess()
{
    if (!processStartedFlag) return false;
    l_batchProcess.CancelOutputRead();
    l_batchProcess.CancelErrorRead();
    l_batchProcess.Close();
    processStartedFlag = false;
    return true;
}
```

**EDIT :** Sorry I think from my question it appears that the process is still running in the normal course , I meant when I explicitly try to close the process.

Comment: From the names of your variables it appears you are running trying to run a Batch File from your code. Would it be possible to switch to a [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) script to do what you want to do? .NET has support for [running PowerShell scripts inside of it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.powershell%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: what are the advantages ?

Comment: More control of the PowerShell instance lifetime than a external process. When your program closes, the powershel engine you created closes with it (assuming you put it in a `using` block so it got disposed).

Answer (score 0):

One workaround that seems to be working is directly calling the executables for `CAT.NET` and passing the `arguments` . then I `Kill` the process instead of `Close` . This way I have the control of killing the executable. 
But doesn't seem elegant .
PowerShell does seem an interesting solution.